# Change DIV tag to Iframe with AutoRefresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I dnt have coding knowledge, i have a code with div and it have some contents with one flash file. i would like to make the contents to refresh for every 30secs.

please the content code to add auto refresh

```
        <!-- BEGIN:PAGE -->
    <div id="page">
        <div id="pictureAndLinks">
            <a href="$song.buycd$" target="_blank"><img class="picture" id="picture" onload="showPicture(this, true)" src="$song.picture$" alt="Buy CD!" border=0 /></a>
        </div>

        <h1>Track Information</h1>

        <dl>
            <dt>Title</dt>
                <dd>$song.title$</dd>
            <dt>Artist</dt>
                <dd>$song.artist$</a></dd>
            <dt>Album</dt>
                <dd>$song.album$</a></dd>
            <dt>Duration</dt>
                <dd>$song.mmss$</dd>
            <dt>Year</dt>
                <dd>$song.albumyear$</dd>
            <dt>Genre</dt>
                <dd>$song.genre$</dd>
            <dt>Lyrics</dt>
                <dd class="broad"><pre>$song.lyrics$</pre></dd>
            <dt>Information</dt>
                <dd class="broad">$song.info$</dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
```

Please dnt add php file. because this file works on same location and the same file name. I tried with load.php files its not working.

I think iframe is working on this. I dnt know to change this to Iframe please anybody change it to iframe with autorefresh for 30secs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Add this to the top of your file and the site will refresh every 30 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = setupRefresh;

    function setupRefresh() {
        setTimeout("refreshPage();", 30000);
    }
    function refreshPage() {
        window.location = location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This tag refresh the hole page, page contents with jquery and one flash player. i need to refresh the content only. without refreshing flash file 

please give me a code to refresh the content only

Answer (score 0):

Add in the head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: This tag refresh the hole page, page contents with jquery and one flash player. i need to refresh the content only. without refreshing flash file

Comment: If you're using Iframes, put this tag in the head of the iframe. Or you could use AJAX to dynamically load new content every 30 seconds using the window.setInterval method

Comment: i am not using iframe, i send code to you can you please change to iframe or with auto refresh for 30secs.

Comment: I await doing the needful